# Storing a parameter value to be returned later in delegate callback

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

I have a singleton class and a protocol defined as below. (Simplified)

```
@protocol ClassADelegate <NSObject>

- (void) classADelegateDidFinishSomething:(BOOL) aBool;

@end


@interface ClassA : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ClassADelegate> delegate;

+ (ClassA *) shared;
- (void) methodA:(BOOL) aBool;

@end
```

The `methodA` method causes a chain of asynchronous callbacks internally and finally in a private method needs to call the delegate method like the following way.

```
if (self.delegate)
{
    [self.delegate classADelegateDidFinishSomething:BOOL_FROM_methodA];
}
```

Now `BOOL_FROM_methodA` in the above method must be the same as the `aBool` in the `methodA` method. So I have to store the value of the `aBool` somewhere. Lets say I store it in a private variable `_aBool` like the following and later using this to call the delegate method.

```
- (void) classMethodA:(BOOL) aBool
{
    _aBool = aBool;
    ...
}

- (void) aPrivateMethod
{
    ....

    if (self.delegate)
    {
        [self.delegate classADelegateDidFinishSomething:_aBool];
    }
}
```

This solves the problem if it was guaranteed that no further calls to `classMethodA` is done before the delegate method is called. But imagine the following situation.

```
[[ClassA shared] methodA:YES];
[[ClassA shared] methodA:NO];
```

For the above code, both of the `classADelegateDidFinishSomething` callbacks will have `NO` as their parameter value, even though the 1st `methodA` call has `YES` as its parameter.

I would like to get an elegant solution to the problem without refactoring most of my code.

Comment: To answer this question it is important to know you the async callbacks look like as they have to convey some information about their origin

Comment: Yes they have to convey information about their origins. I used BOOL as an example, it is more complex than that.

Comment: Then you may be able to set up a NSDictionary with some identifier which identifiers your call to methodA and the async callbacks have to convey that identifier so that you can retrieve the corresponding value from the dictionary prior to calling your delegate.  
BTW: I fat fingered my first comment - should be read as "know how the async callbacks look like" :)

Comment: Can you give a simple code? I did not understand you properly. Also the async callbacks are server APIs that I have no control over.

Comment: Can you show some code about how you trigger  those async callbacks? In particular the one in which you will call `aPrivateMethod`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're implementing something that requires context (multiple requests) using structures that are inherently one-to-one (singleton, delegate).  This isn't a good match.

Options that come to mind are to use a unique instance of `ClassA` for each invocation of `methodA` or to rewrite `ClassA` methods so that the caller supplies its own context.

For example:

```
- (void)classMethodA:(BOOL)aBool listener:(id<ClassADelegate>)listener;
```

That way, you could map each call to the object that made it.

---

Or, if there's only one delegate making multiple calls, replace the `listener` object with any kind of `context` parameter that can be used to tag the calls.

```
- (void)classMethodA:(BOOL)aBool context:(id)context;
- (void)aPrivateMethod:(id)context;
```

For either of those options, your singleton can maintain a collection that maps calls to responses.